# Error in Fitdist in for loop

Tags: r

I am running the below code, i.e to save the AIC values for negative binomial distribution in a vector.

The data file is available at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m5iqkmfacu257hh/SOFQ1.csv?dl=0

```
samples <- read.table(file.choose(), header = FALSE, sep = ",")
nbinom_aic <- data.frame(NBINOM_AIC = numeric(0))
for(i in 1:336) {
  a <- samples[, i]
  d <- fitdist(a, distr = "nbinom") 
  nbinom_aic <- rbind(nbinom_aic, d$aic)
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

> Error in fitdist(a, distr = "nbinom") : the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, with the error code 100
>
> In addition:
>
> produced 2: In sqrt(1/diag(V)) : NaNs produced 3: In cov2cor(varcovar)
>   : diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful
>
> Warning messages: 1: In sqrt(diag(varcovar)) : NaNs

Also the output only contains 62 values, whereas I am expecting 336 values as I have 336 sets of distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adding a debugging code in yours:

```
for(i in 1:336) {
  a <- samples[, i]
  print(i)
  d <- fitdist(a, distr = "nbinom") 
  nbinom_aic <- rbind(nbinom_aic, d$aic)
}
```

You will find your code stop at `i=63`

Now check what's the data looks like:

```
a <- samples[, 63]
summary(a)
```

There are all 0s. I think this is the reason why fitdist failed.

To work around this if you want to `fitdist` all columns, just need to check the whether there is only 1 unique value and it is 0.

Comment: Thanks Sixiang... it worked..removed all the columns which had only 0s..